# Script for fasta sequence replacement based on header name

Tags: alignment, fasta

I have two fasta file (one file has about 50,000 and another has 150,000 sequences) with two kinds of header formats. I want to replace sequences of interest in one file based on header name (I have two list of headers for two fasta files as txt format). Could you please advise me what should I do?

For example header format for file 1 and 2 are as `>contig10002|m.12543` and `>c26528_g1_i1|m.14066`, respectively, and I want to replace the related sequence of `>c26528_g1_i1|m.14066` in file 2 with related sequence of `>contig10002|m.12543`.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion is to use [BioPython](http://biopython.org/wiki/Main_Page). It can parse fasta files and format them and it can possibly handle headers in different formats.

For example here is how you can read a fasta file and loop over the IDs:

```
fasta_sequences = SeqIO.parse(open('file1.fasta'),'fasta')
for fasta in fasta_sequences:
    # do something with fasta.id, e.g. >c26528_g1_i1|m.14066
```

Here is how you would write a fasta record:

```
with open(output_file, 'w') as output_handle:
for fasta in fasta_sequences:
    SeqIO.write([fasta], output_handle, "fasta")
```

You might want to start reading the [BioPyton Tutorial and Coookbook](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html)